# How to solve Hoffman & Kunze exercise 8, section 10.2?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form, representations-by-quadratic-forms

Let $A$ be a symmetric $n×n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $q$ be the quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $q(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}x_ix_j$. Show that there is an invertible linear operator $U$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $q(U(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n))=\sum_{i=1}^n c_{i}x_i^2$, where $c_i$'s are $0,1$ or $-1$.

I have solved the above problem by using the fact that any symmetric bilinear form on a finite-dimensional real vector space can be represented by some diagonal matrix with diagonal entries in 0, 1 or -1 with respect to some ordered basis. But the next exercise 9 asks to prove the same fact using this problem. So, I was wondering if one can solve the problem without using the fact that symmetric bilinear forms are "diagonalizable" (in some sense).

Comment: At some point you have to complete the square.....

Comment: Not always (e.g. $x_1x_2=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}2\right)^2$). Use [Gauss's reduction algorithm (on Wikipedia in French)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9duction_de_Gauss#Cas_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral). Surprisingly, I found no post on this site describing it, and no dedicated page on Wikipedia in English. It seems (?) better known to French-speaking mathematicians, teachers, students. If there really is no previous post to link to, I can edit an answer (essentially translating the Wikipedia French page).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the reference. I got some ideas from it, I'd try it on my own again.